# Python map() function- return first 10 results

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a data set that has different characteristics about football players (name, age, speed, team, etc)

Right now I want to know the top 10 youngest players.

I have already collected all the players by their name and age with the `map()` function, but I just want to print the first 10 results.

**This is my actual code:**

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("CustomerExpenditure")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

def age(line):
    fields = line.split(",")

    return(str(fields[0]), str(fields[14]))


file = sc.textFile("file:///Users/carlos/PycharmProjects/NONSQL/Project/FullData.csv")

oldestsPlayers = file.map(age)

topOldestPlayers = oldestsPlayers.map(lambda x: (x[1], x[0])).sortByKey()


results=topOldestPlayers.collect()



for result in results:
        print(result)
```

**This is the output:**

```
('33', 'Nathan Rutjes') 
('33', 'Jeppe Curth') 
('33', 'Ognjen Vukojević') 
('33', 'Marco Padalino') 
('33', 'Brian Murphy') 
('33', 'Adrián Cortés') 
('33', 'Yaír Urbina') 
('33', 'Kim Chi Gon')
('33', 'Jacques Faty')
('33', 'Sander Asevedo')
('33', 'Alan Besseiro')
('33', 'Sandro Couteiro')
('33', 'Murilo Sancha')
('33', 'Mateus Couteira')
('33', 'Peixotacinho')
('33', 'Danisco Fachini')
('33', 'Fabiem Jardim')
('33', 'Carlos Travisso')
('33', 'Maksymilian Rogalski')
('33', 'César Valoyes')
('33', 'Dougie Imrie')
('33', 'Darren Jones')
('33', 'Iacopo La Rocca')
('33', 'Dioh Williams')
('33', 'David Fox')
('33', 'Michael Tonge')
('33', 'Paul Green')
```

Comment: Have you tried `print(results[:10])`?

Comment: It is an option, but I want to print it line by line. If I just do ```print(results[10])```, this is the ouput: 
```[('17', 'Matthijs de Ligt'), ('17', 'Justin Kluivert'), ('17', 'Kai Havertz'), ('17', 'Alexander Isak'), ('17', 'Abdülkadir Ömür'), ('17', 'Misael Domínguez'), ('17', 'José Gomes'), ('17', 'Alessandro Bastoni'), ('17', 'Boubacar Kamara'), ('17', 'Zaydou Youssouf')]
```
I would like something like: 
```
Carlos: 17
Pepe: 17
Juan: 18
...
```

Comment: `for r in results[:10]: print(r)` those are the basics of python.

Comment: Thanks, I know that are basics, but I'm learning on my own, so there are still some functions which I don't know. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

when you use a collect, you bring back all the data, and then you filter. Which means that with a tons of data, you may crash your memory.

```
results = topOldestPlayers.take(10)
```

this method will only bring the top 10 without having everything. 
then, if you just want to print them,

```
for r in results: print(*r, sep=': ')
```